# Unit test the call count of method in then part of a promise in Jasmine and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In code below, userService.addPreference is mocked, and so is $state.go, but still the call count of $state.go is always zero. Is there something I may have missed in the setup of userService.addPreference mocked method?

**Code that is being unit tested**

```
      userService.addPreference(preference).then(function (dashboard) {
              $state.go('authenticated.dashboard.grid', {id: dashboard.id});
            });
```

**Unit Test Mocked methods and the Unit Test**

```
sinon.stub(userService, 'addPreference', function (preference) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(preference);
                return defer.promise;
            });
sinon.stub($state, 'go', function () { });
    it('dashboard.confirm should call $state.go', function () {
        vm.confirm();//this is the function containing code being unit tested
        expect($state.go.callCount).to.equal(1);//this is always ZERO and so failing
    });
```

Comment: Since the call is asyn in nature, can you inject $rootScope and call $apply function before doing any assertion?

Comment: I have injected $rootScope and in my code 'scope = $rootScope().$new();', so I guess I should add this line ' scope.$apply();' just before assertion?

Comment: Yes that solved my problem. Can you please post your suggestion as an answer? So I just added scope.$apply() just before the line of code that says 'expect($state.go.callCount)...'.

Comment: Could you also explain why should scope.$apply ( ) be called in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service call

```
userService.addPreference(preference).then(function (dashboard) {
              $state.go('authenticated.dashboard.grid', {id: dashboard.id});
            });
```

involves a async callback, which will not fire unless we explicitly tell it to. To force the callback to evaluate we need to run a digest cycle using `$scope.$apply`, so change your test code to:

```
  it('dashboard.confirm should call $state.go', function () {
        vm.confirm();//this is the function containing code being unit tested
        $scope.$apply();
        expect($state.go.callCount).to.equal(1);//this is always ZERO and so failing
    });
```

Remember is a sequential flow callback are never fired.

Comment: You mean when testing async callbacks are normally never fired?

Comment: Since javascript is a single threaded execution, once you make async call nothing waits for the result and you continue to the next step, in your case that is assert and it fails. By doing $apply you are forcing Angular to evaluate callbacks,

Comment: Great. You have taught me so much in such a small period. Thanks.